# How to run a job only on sunday?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

After a search i find this solution but i think it doesn't work correctly.

```
0 20 * * 7
```

Comment: That is the correct syntax for running a job on Sunday at 8pm. What is "not working"?

Comment: see this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19480/cron-job-asterisk-meaning/19483#19483

Comment: doesn't work because the job is not started! I've a Mage::log(something in the job to check if it start.
Now i modified the cron to "0 20 * * 0"